# IIS 7.5 Directory Access Denied When File.Copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When i try to copy files with System.IO.File.Copy() with ASP.Net C# in IIS 7.5 i get directory access denied error.

I've added almost every possible users that could need a permission on that folder :

***IIS APPPOOL.Net v4.5 Classic***

***IUSR***

**IIS_IUSRS**

Didn't work. I've then added same permissions to the parent folder , but i still can't make it work.

PS  : I don't use the inetpub directory for this application. It doesn't even located in the system partition (e.g. C:\) . Its in somewhere else and its sync with Google Drive. But i can travel through files with these permissions.

So what do you all think it could be ?

Comment: Instead of giving access to random account check what account actually tries to access file (`Environment.UserName`). Also show code that copies files - note that your post contains inconsistent statements - you claim to copy files, but say that error is about access to directory (clearly if you try to copy file over existing directory or directy as file you'll get an error, so your post definitely need editing to align two statements).

Comment: It seems that you were right. I didn't see that but i was actually trying to copy whole directory to another with File.Copy(). So i've gone through the code again and fixed it. Now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I know this is kinda old... But how did you fixed it? Mine is still 'Access is denied' error... I have a client-server setup and I cant transfer a file from client to server...

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **FileMon** to identify the exact account that is trying to copy the files and getting the access denied error.
2. once you identify the account, give necessary permissions to it, instead of giving access to random accounts which could result in security issues.

Comment: My problem was whole lot of different apparenly. But back then when i thought it was about the permissions, i've used ProcessMonitor(which apparently is a replace for FileMon, i've found about thanks to you) and caught the name of user that was trying to access to folder.